# Not getting Record Between two dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get rows between 2 dates

Here is the query:

```
select 
    distinct Convert(varchar(09), [DateTime], 103)
from 
    StudentAttendance_FK 
where 
    LecturerID = 5033 and 
    CourseID = 1004 and 
    SubjectID = 120 and 
    [DateTime] Between '3/8/2012' and '3/11/2012'
```

Format (MM/DD/YYYY)

Sample values

```
3/8/2012 11:40:46 PM
3/8/2012 11:40:46 PM
3/9/2012 11:57:55 AM
3/9/2012 10:48:02 PM
3/10/2012 11:57:20 PM
```

The query isn't returning any rows between these two dates. Any changes in this query?

thanks you

Ajay.

Comment: I don't know if you are querying some dates in March or if you mean the third in a month. Perhaps SQL Server also is confused. Try changing the date format to `yyyymmdd`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the [DateTime] values without the range filter in place, and also without the convert?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 103 (`d/m/y`) then why is your where clause using `m/d/y`? Are you using British/Canadian regional settings or not? Stick to standard, unambiguous formats such as `yyyymmdd` and you will have much more predictable results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]) 
FROM dbo.StudentAttendance_FK
WHERE LecturerID = 5033
AND CourseID = 1004
AND SubjectID = 120
AND [DateTime] >= '20120308' AND [DateTime] < '20120312';
```